# How to get UI elements in diffrent Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, task

In my app I'm saving data to my database (SQLite).
I don't want to block my UI so I save the data in diffrent task

```
            await Task.Run(() => this.SaveTracks(books, filesCollection));
```

I get TextBox from my dictionary with data

```
TextBox tmpTextBox = parseData["title_" + i] as TextBox;
```

When it wasn't in diffrent Task it works great but when I've set in with Task.Run I get Exception that I can't use it cause I invoke element in diffrent thread. How can I not block my UI by doing it in diffrent Task and get data from UI elements in main Thread

Comment: after await task you can update ui. Please add more info or code.
What SaveTracks returns? Describe what you are need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `TextBox.Text` value before you start the Task and pass that value as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- Split up the bigger operation so that your loop (I assume there's a loop) still executes in the UI thread, but each individual save operation is a separate task in the background
- Fetch *all* the UI information you need before you create the task, and capture that information so the task never needs to access the UI

Either way the result is the same: you only access the UI elements in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I've took biggest loop that does not need UI data into diffrent threads. It did great. UI elements are collected in main thread. Thank you